# Selecting rows from a table by One a field from other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What i want, to display rows from a table which is selected by a field from other table single value, lets say to display images from a table by last category id.

I have this type of query, but this return me all matching keys rows, if i inset LIMIT 1 then it return one row...

```
SELECT i.prof_image FROM profile_images i
JOIN images_cat cat ON (cat.cat_id = i.cat_id)
GROUP BY i.prof_image; 
//OR LIMIT 1;
```

Any idea to fix this problem. (i.e. displaying the latest category images)?

Comment: Can you include some sample data and desired output please?

Comment: im not sure i get your problem, but my guess is you are missing a "DISTINCT" in your query.
SELECT DISTINCT i.prof_image ....

Comment: @Rufinus,@james C: No i simply want to display the category images. by latest added category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for your specific example.. If you need to be more selective, then please post some more details..

```
SELECT i.prof_image 
FROM profile_images i 
WHERE cat_id = (select max(cat_id) from images_cat)
```

Comment: why subselect it ? MAX(i.cat_id) should do exactly the same.

Comment: @StevieG, yes this is possible but i wnat single query mean by joining.

Comment: @StevieG give me the error... Error Code : 1111
Invalid use of group function
(0 ms taken)

Comment: I've changed it back to the original solution, doesn't look like you can do this without a sub-select (I'll keep trying though!)..

Comment: This one only display field title, but no data within it. And i check both individually so they work..

Comment: Does the max(cat_id) in images_cat actually exist in profile_images? This would really be a lot easier if you could post some example data

Comment: actually, can you also post the table structure too.. this might be possible without a subselect if you have a timestamp on the tables..

Comment: @StevieG, all right now, some internal problem sorry, and thanx for help but can we display it by joining...

Comment: @stevieG argh.. of course a group function, but group by i.prof_image should fix this. 
@ime structure and sample data, would make this so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.id
```

This query will grab all things in table_2 that have the same id value.

Note that it is a LEFT JOIN - which means that if there are *no* matching values in table_2, it will still return the values from table_1.

What is your intent with using last()?

Hope this helps.

Comment: NO, this is not simple as you write,

Comment: @ime Sorry it didn't help, don't need to yell :P. Did you find your answer?

Comment: yes, StevieG answer is help me, but not yet for taking as one query. mean to pickup record by JOINS>.... And thanks for your reply man.